# Pandas: Joining information from multiple data frames, array

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have three data structures:

1. A data frame `df1`, with columns `A, B, C` of length 10000
2. A data frame `df2`, with columns `A, some extra misc. columns...` of length 8000
3. A Python list `labels` of length 8000, where the element at index `i` corresponds with row `i` in `df2`.

I'm trying to create a data frame from this information that, for every element in `df2.a`, I grab the relevant row from `df1` and `labels` to pair up this information. It's possible that an entry in `df2.A` is NOT present in `df1.A`.

Currently, I'm doing this through a `for i in xrange(len(df2))` loop, checking if `df2.A.iloc[i]` is present in `df1.A`, and if it is, I store `df1.A, df1.B, df1.C, labels[i]` into a dictionary with the first element as the key and the rest of the elements as a list.

Is there a more efficient way to do this and store the outputs `df1.A, df1.B, df1.C, labels[i]` into a 4 columns dataframe? The for loop is really slow.

Sample data:

```
df1
A       B       C
'uid1'  'Bob'   'Rock'
'uid2'  'Jack'  'Pop'
'uid5'  'Cat'   'Country'
...

df2
A
'uid10'
'uid3'
'uid1'
...

labels
[label10, label3, label1, ...]
```

Comment: Can you post data as there may be subtle problems with various approaches. So essentially df2 is your master df and you want to create a new df where df2.A is in df1.A and if so use the row values from df1 and the corresponding labels, is this correct?

Comment: I posted some example data above. df2 is basically only being used so I know which relevant element of ```labels``` I want to join with a row of ```df1```. But yeah, you understood what I'm trying to do correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK from what I understand the following should work:

```python
# create a new column for your labels, this will align to your index
df2['labels'] = labels
# now merge the rows from df1 on column 'A'
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='A', how='left')
```

Example:

```python
# setup my sample data
temp="""A       B       C
'uid1'  'Bob'   'Rock'
'uid2'  'Jack'  'Pop'
'uid5'  'Cat'   'Country'"""

temp1="""A
'uid10'
'uid3'
'uid1'"""
labels = ['label10', 'label3', 'label1']
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1))

In [97]:
# do the work
df2['labels'] = labels
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='A', how='left')
df2
Out[97]:
         A   labels      B       C
0  'uid10'  label10    NaN     NaN
1   'uid3'   label3    NaN     NaN
2   'uid1'   label1  'Bob'  'Rock'
```

This will be considerably faster than looping